# How to implement SAML in express application?

Tags: node.js, express, saml

I am new in SAML, I want to implement SAML authentication in my node(express) application. I dont know how to create IDP and service provider any one explain. please.

Answer (score 0):

The IDP is external to you.

To implement the SP, you need a client side [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).